# How can I get sshd to tell me why it's failing public key authentications?

Tags: ssh, logging, authentication, public-key

I'm using OpenSSH 6.9p1 (on Lubuntu) as my SSH server. When trying to connect to it (using an SSH client in Cygwin), I keep being reverted to password authentication, despite having properly generated my keys, put them in the authorized key file on the server, checked the permissions etc.

So, I look in `/var/log/auth.log` to see what the server says. I find this:

```
Nov  1 09:50:10 er-thinkpad sshd[16148]: Accepted password for joeuser from 192.168.2.6 port 53325 ssh2
Nov  1 09:50:10 er-thinkpad sshd[16148]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user joeuser by (uid=0)
Nov  1 09:50:10 er-thinkpad systemd-logind[590]: New session 497 of user joeuser.
```

... and nothing before that first line about the public key authentication failure. Ok, let's increase the verbosity maybe. So I change `LogLevel` from `INFO` to `VERBOSE` and try again. Now I get:

```
Nov  1 09:53:12 er-thinkpad sshd[16269]: Connection from 192.168.2.6 port 53349 on 192.168.2.2 port 22
Nov  1 09:53:12 er-thinkpad sshd[16269]: Failed publickey for joeuser from 192.168.2.6 port 53349 ssh2: RSA SHA256:removedthis
Nov  1 09:53:12 er-thinkpad sshd[16269]: Failed publickey for joeuser from 192.168.2.6 port 53349 ssh2: ECDSA SHA256:removedthis
Nov  1 09:53:15 er-thinkpad sshd[16269]: Accepted password for joeuser from 192.168.2.6 port 53349 ssh2
Nov  1 09:53:15 er-thinkpad sshd[16269]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user joeuser by (uid=0)
Nov  1 09:53:15 er-thinkpad systemd-logind[590]: New session 499 of user joeuser.
Nov  1 09:53:15 er-thinkpad sshd[16269]: User child is on pid 16271
Nov  1 09:53:15 er-thinkpad sshd[16271]: Starting session: shell on pts/5 for joeuser from 192.168.2.6 port 53349
```

So great, it failed, but **why** did it fail? How can I get sshd to tell me that?

---

PS - Just so you know, here's what the client sees:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_dsa for not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/joeuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed (and deleted my comment).  But there are levels above `VERBOSE`, and now might be a good time to try them.

Comment: @Iain: Can you explain which elements from the list of necessary ones you think are missing? Note the question has been given a reasonable answer already, so enough info was available to allow that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the server side, set the log level to `DEBUG3`. On the client side, connect with the `-vvv` option (which gives you `DEBUG3` on the client side as well).

Comment: I mistakenly assumed DEBUG would only add, well, debugging-related log messages rather than useful information, but I guess I should have seen that coming.

Comment: @einpoklum So what was the problem?

Comment: line breaks in the `authorized_keys2` entry (which looked like wrapping).

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks,  that was it for me too. So frustrating!

Comment: It was a problem with SELinux for me.